# recommend a Satelite internet provider

Tags: internet, providers, satellite

A part of our team is in Afghanistan and they are now asking me to find an internet solution for their office.
The only option I can think of is satellite internet access, but unfortunately I do not have any experience with equipment like that. So I am asking you to recommend some one who can cover Middle East, who is also connected with Europe because that is where our main office is located. Allowing us to easily make payments and agreements.

We do not have a need for a super stable and fast link, a 2MB upload and 512KB download will be just fine for our purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a project I was involved with in Mosul Iraq we used [Horizon Satellite Services](http://www.horizon-satellite.com/).  It was only a 512kbs/512kbs connection, but I am almost positive they offer up to 2MB service.  The connection, though horribly latent (who would have guessed), was very stable.  However they are based out of Dubai, but have some sort of presence in Germany.  Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: of course it help, Subquestion Did you bought equipment from they or somewhere else, And if is not secret whet is approximate price for this kind of link

Comment: I think it was about $10k for the hardware and around $400/month.  Not cheap.

Comment: Using something like a Riverbed Steelhead WAN accelerator on the link might help.  Depends on your traffic but have heard of users with satellite links getting great results.

Answer (score -2):

You wont see that kind of upload speed on a satellite internet connection.  You can get about a 10th of the download speed for upload.  The ones I have dealt with are incredible slow and it was sometimes easier to just dial-up into the site.  The latency is what makes it so slow.

Comment: Your right about latency being an issue, but so long as the traffic doesn't timeout it's not a huge issue. As for speed I know Hughes Net offers up to 5Mbs (could be higher now) and most satallite connections upload speed can be picked. It's not uncommon to have a fast upload then down.

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks for the information.  Didn't know you could actually get decent upload.  Looks like a max upload would be 10Mbps.